# Why does webpack ignore chunk in production mode?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

I have multiple entry points that share same code. What I need to do is to extract this code into one file using `splitCode` in webpack 4. This works fine in `development` mode but not in `production`.

Configuration file:

```
var path = require('path');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const WebpackMd5Hash = require("webpack-md5-hash");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {

                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(sass|scss|css)$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader",
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        chunkFilename: 'js/[name]-[chunkhash].js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: "jQuery"
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: "single",
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendor",
                    chunks: "all",
                    priority: 1
                },
                utilities: {
                    test: /\.s?js$/,
                    minChunks: 2,
                    name: "utilities",
                    chunks: "all",
                    priority: 0
                }
            }
        }
    },
    context: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets'),
    entry: {
        a: './js/a.js',
        b: './js/b.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['public/js/*.*', 'public/css/*.*'], {} ),

        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name]-[contenthash].css"
        }),

        new WebpackMd5Hash(),

        new ManifestPlugin({
            fileName: 'manifest.json'
        }),
    ]
};
```

In development mode Webpack creates two entry points, one `runtime.js`, `vendor.js` and `utilities.js` which is ok.

When I change mode from `development` to `production`, webpack ignores `utilities` cacheGroups and appends common codebase into two entry points.

What am I missing?

Webpack version: 4.28.4
Node version: 8.15

Answer (score 3):

It seems like setting `enforce` to `true` does the job (but I'm not entirely really sure why).

It should be like this:

```
utilities: {
    test: /\.s?js$/,
    minChunks: 2,
    name: "utilities",
    chunks: "all",
    priority: 0,
    enforce: true
}
```

From now on, `utilities.js` is being created not only in development mode, but also in production.

Answer (score 2):

### It's not a bug. It's a feature

Webpack 4 `splitchunks.cacheGroups` is ignored in production mode **IF** the new chunk is less than the size of 30kb.

### solution to override this default condition:

user `splitchunks.cacheGroups.runtime.enforce: true` if you want to really make sure that these chunks are created

Check the documention for further details https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#defaults

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `minChunks: 2` means it will only create a split bundle if the given common imports is specified in at least 2 modules. You might want to verify but dropping it to 1.

There are few additional default rules listed here: https://gist.github.com/sokra/1522d586b8e5c0f5072d7565c2bee693#defaults but mainly if the common codebase isn't larger than 30kb (before min+gz) then it won't get split out. You can force it by updated the key `minSize` as listed [in the default optimization config](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#optimization-splitchunks).

Answer (score 0):

Webpack `SplitChunksPlugin`, by [default](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#defaults), ignores any chunk smaller than 30kb. If you run Webpack in development mode, you'll be able to see the bundle size of `utilities.js` and enforce the split by setting `optimization.splitChunks.minSize` option smaller than the size of `utilities.js`.